# how do you generate 20 random numbers in python

Tags: python, random, integer

I'm trying to generate 20 random numbers in python and say whether they are odd or even, this is what I have so far:

```
import random

def main():

    i = 0
    num = 0

    #while loop
    while i<20:

       #user enters input
        num = random.randint(input("enter lowest number:\t"))
        i = random.randint(input("enter highest number:\t"))

        #if else
        if num>=0 and num<=100:

            num = num+i

            i = i +1

            print(num)

        else:
            print("error")

        #for loop
        for i in range(num):


main()
```

would someone be able to help me finish it as I'm completely lost

here is the question:

Write a program which generates 20 random integers and indicates whether each number is odd or even.  The program should begin by asking the user to input two integers which will act as the range for the generation of 20 random integers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate 20 random integers and indicate whether each number is odd or even](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441579/generate-20-random-integers-and-indicate-whether-each-number-is-odd-or-even)

Comment: Simple: `range(20)`... [That's the problem with randomness... You can never be sure](http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def odd_or_even(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(num, 'is even')
    else:
        print(num, 'is not even')

lst = [random.randint(lower, upper) for x in range(20)]
for num in lst:
    print(even_or_odd(num))
```

Here is a working program but if you couldn't be bothered to figure this out I doubt you are going to enjoy this class very much as it's only going to get more difficult.

Comment: Fair point. I believe that 0 is considered even. Am I wrong? http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57188.html

Comment: @Floris: Absolutely zero is even!  And since `1` fails the `num % 2 == 0` test, there's no need for the first branch in the `if` statement at all.

Answer (score 4):

use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
import random
lower = int(raw_input("enter lowest number:\t"))
greater = int(raw_input("enter highest number:\t"))
print [random.randint(lower, greater) for a in range(100)]
```

Comment: Use `raw_input` if you run this on Python 2.x.

Comment: ah sorry, copypasta from OP's content, thanks @Matthias

Answer (score 4):

I would rather rewrite that function completely

```
import random


def main():
    lower = int(raw_input("enter lowest number: "))
    upper = int(raw_input("enter highest number: "))
    for i in range(20):
        num = random.randint(lower, upper)
        print(num)
main()
```

I think you will be able to easily modify it to suite your needs :)

EDIT: As suggested, I rewrote the function so it wouldnt ask for lower and upper bound every step of for loop, but only once before entering the for loop. Which is much less annoying and probably the thing you wanted to do.

Comment: With this function you will have to enter the lowest/highest number every time the loop runs.

Comment: how do you make the loop continuous that you just type in 2 numbers on the first go and it will give you 20 random numbers??

Comment: user3250465: I just rewrote it that way, as IanAuld suggested

Comment: thanks man :) do you know how to say whether each number is even or odd as well??

Comment: How would you try to figure out if a number is odd or even? If you divide a number by 2 and the remainder is 0 the number is even. Now go and code that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import time

start = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    random.choice([i for i in range(1000)])
print 'random.choice()', time.time() - start

start = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    random.randint(0,1000)
print 'random.randint()', time.time() - start

start = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    int(random.random() * 1000)
print 'random.random()', time.time() - start
```

**[out]:**

```
random.choice() 0.849874973297
random.randint() 0.015105009079
random.random() 0.00372695922852
```

Comment: What is this an answer for?

Answer (score 0):

First ask the user the top and bottom numbers,
Then use a generator to get the numbers.

```
import random

def randnums(number, startnum=0, endnum=100):
    for i in range(1, number + 1):
         yield random.randint(startnum, endnum)

def getparams():
    return int(input('Lowest number: ')), int(input('Highest number: '))

def main():
    bottom, top = getparams()
    nums = list(randnums(20, startnum=bottom, endnum=top))
    for number in nums:
        print(number, ',', sep='')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```